# Multiple shaders or one big shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I want to draw models with textures and lighting as well as only wireframes of other models, which need no lighting.

What is the recommended way to do that? Do i write two separate fragment shaders and switch between them, or is it better to write one shader which disables lighting on the fly?

Comment: You actually posted first, but this is almost the same question as this, which came just a few minutes later: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33962945/3530129.

Comment: Nice coincidence, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw both in the same scene (and even if you don't)it is probably better to have two shader programs, since opengl only needs to switch between them. It will be efficient and you won't be having to check for lighting use in the shaders using uniforms or another way.